# How to save HTML code in Sql Server database for correct display?

Tags: java, html, sql, sql-server

My website is just like Stack Overflow and under development. I am using plain textarea to take text input as I do not have any WMD editor like Stack Overflow's.

When I take HTML code as input and store it in database table in a text or `nvarchar(max)` column, it is stored successfully. But when I call that data for display, it displays the corresponding HTML page instead of that HTML code on screen. I am not able to resolve it. For better understanding I'm putting here input page and output page images of my website.

This is image of input page:

[image]

This is the image of output page:

[image]

What is going wrong here ?

Comment: You need to escape the HTML so it's not interpreted by the browser. How to do that depends on the view technology you're using. What are you using to display? JSP? There's nothing wrong with the way you're saving the data, only the display part is wrong.

Comment: Yes. I am using jsp and html for display.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another possible solution is to replace the html tags before storing in database. What I did is :-

```
text=text.replaceAll("<", "&lt;");
text=text.replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
```

and then stored text in database and its working. Thanks to Bibin Mathew.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to replace

```
< with &lt; and > with &gt;
```

in the HTML string which you retrived and then display it on page.

Have you tried that ?

Comment: Yes its working. But I want to work it like Stackoverflow does. No user of my website will take care to follow these instructions while inputting the code. Any other working solution ?

Comment: yes, So why do you want user to do that . You get the input from the user in normal HTML format save it in the DB retrive it into a string variable and do a string.replace to replace the tags .  And now display it in the UI ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the HTML so it's not interpreted by the browser. How to do that depends on the view technology you're using.

With JSP and JSTL the escaping is automatically done with `<c:out value="${myString}"/>`. If you're not using JSTL yet, now's the time to start (there's a lot of other helpful things in there too).

Answer (score 0):

you can save the html codes just like text. You can use varchar(max) type column to save the html code in table. Display the code is depending the browser. But if you use nvarchar type that will cause problems in display.